# How to debug a coalescing null statement that involves method calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have the following statement:

```
var instance = GetLastActiveInstance() ?? AppInstance.FindOrRegisterInstanceForKey(App.Id.ToString());
```

When I place a breakpoint at the above statement and step through, how can I know whether the `??` operator chose the left-hand side or the right-hand side?  Is there a trick for this?  I am using Visual Studio 2019, but I also would be happy to hear a solution for VS Code.

If there had been a variable used in either of the two sides, I could hover over the variable and see its value.  But with method calls, the only solution seems to first assign at least one method call's result to a temporary variable.  But of course, that results in code modification.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint inside both the methods? OR when you are on the line you hit F11

Comment: @MickyD That doesn't work, statement split over multiple lines still results in a single breakpoint.

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, that's a good point.  I was wondering whether there's a way (some sort of trick that Visual Studio provides), that would work without having to go into the individual methods.  Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @MickyD I had already tried it before posting my response to you.  Please see here: https://imgur.com/1aEmZDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a breakpoint inside both the methods? OR when you are on the line you hit F11

Comment: I tried the F11 approach.  Execution jumped into the `GetLastActiveInstance()` method.  I debugged that method and saw that it returned `null`.  Then back at the `??` statement, hitting F11 again did not take me into the second method (`FindOrRegisterInstanceForKey()`).
Not a problem, just that Visual Studio assumes that after going into the first method, you wouldn't be interested going into any other methods on the same line. :)

Comment: @Sabuncu that not correct. If the first method returns null it will go into second method. please check again

Comment: I see what happened.  `FindOrRegisterInstanceForKey()` is part of the framework, and there is no source for it.  F11 did not go into it because it couldn't.  Thanks for setting me straight.